# How do I silence Network.Browser.browse's logs to stdout?

Tags: networking, haskell

I'm using [Network.Browser](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HTTP/4000.0.9/doc/html/Network-Browser.html) 4000.0.9 to retrieve a web page:

```
import Network.Browser
import Network.HTTP

main =
  do
    (uri, response) <- browse $ do
      setAllowRedirects True
      setDebugLog Nothing
      request $ getRequest "http://www.google.com/robots.txt"
    putStrLn "done"
```

Despite `setDebugLog Nothing` this spews all of this logging:

```
Sending:
GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
User-Agent: ...
Content-Length: 0


Creating new connection to www.google.com
Received:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
...
```

How do I turn this logging off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setOutHandler` and `setErrHandler` as described in the documentation page you linked.

Comment: Thanks. Slightly embarrassed... I should RTFM.