# Log networks requests

Tags: haskell, networking

Having this code:

```
import Data.Conduit.Binary (sinkFile)
 import Network.HTTP.Conduit
 import qualified Data.Conduit as C

 main :: IO ()
 main = do
      request <- parseUrl "http://google.com/"
      withManager $ \manager -> do
          response <- http request manager
          responseBody response C.$$+- sinkFile "google.html"
```

How do I log it: write to the console or a file all the events and data sent/received? I didn't find any mention about logging in the documentation.

Comment: In what documentation?  It sounds like you are trying to learn some framework without learning the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sinkFile doesn't do any logging.  If you want a conduit that does some logging in addition to what sinkFile does, you'll have to write it yourself, although it should be relatively simple.

```
logSinkFile filename = logSinkIOHandle (IO.openBinaryFile fp IO.WriteMode)

logSinkIOHandle alloc = bracketP alloc IO.hClose logSinkHandle

logSinkHandle h = go
 where go = do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "Awaiting data."
    mbs <- await
    case mbs of
     Nothing -> return ()
     Maybe bs -> do
        liftIO $ do
            putStrLn "Data Ready."
            putStr "Writing data: "
            S.put bs
            putStrLn ""
            S.hPut h bs
            putStrLn "Data written."
        go
```

Or something like that.

Comment: how do I apply this to my example?

Comment: actually, I want logging like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074863/how-do-i-silence-network-browser-browses-logs-to-stdout

Comment: http-client does not do any logging internally, unlike Network.  If you want logging, you'll have to start the lowest-level things http-client provides and compose them with your logging.  Like in the example.

Comment: Assuming my code works (it's pedantic, not practical in nature), you'd call replace the call to `sinkFile` in your original example with a call to my `logSinkFile`.

Comment: For "Creating New Connection", you can replace/enhance the `Manager`'s  manager*Connection hooks, making changes to add your logging.  For the sending, you can alter the `Popper` values inside the `RequestBody` to log as they produce more bytes.  For the receiving, something similiar to my example will work for http-conduit.

Comment: Look at [`setOutHandler`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.17/docs/Network-Browser.html#v:setOutHandler); that will be the primary location.  Using (e.g.) putStrLn will get you some logging.  Also see `setErrHandler` and `setEventHandler` from the same package.